# How to change the memory priority of a scheduled task?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, scheduled-tasks

When starting my program without Task Scheduler, it has memory priority of 5 like all other programs running in my system (Windows 7).

But when running under Task Scheduler, it has memory priority of 4, and it impact performance.

Note! Process priority is Normal (CPU Priority 8) so this is not the problem! Only memory priority is the problem!

Process Explorer screenshot:

[image: Memory Priority 4, Process Explorer]

How to change the memory priority of a scheduled task to 5? Win32 API is an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently there's no way to tell Task Scheduler to not adjust the memory priority. But it can be done programmatically. See this thread over at Serverfault: https://serverfault.com/questions/151824/process-runs-slower-as-a-scheduled-task-than-it-does-interactively

Answer (score 3):

this is an old question, but maybe I can help someone. To change the priority of a scheduled task export the task (to an xml file), edit that file, search for the priority line and change the number. Values go from 0 (real-time priority) to 10 (idle priority). After changing the value, import the task and test if now it meets your requirements of CPU, Memory and I/O priority.

Comment: _Memory Priority_ is not the same as _(Process) Priority_. See Mattias answer.